# How to create 0..1 to 0..1 relationship with a "shared" PK?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have following table structure:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Knowledge Knowledge { get; set; }
}

public class Knowledge
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have 0..1-0..1 relationship between `Product` and `Knowledge`, with `Knowledge.Id` being both PK and FK to `Product`. I following [this guide](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/) and with this code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // see: http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasRequired(e => e.Knowledge)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I get a 1-0..1 relationship. But I do not want `Knowledge` to have a FK Constraint, i.e. I want be able to create `Knowledge` without corresponding `Product`. Is that possible? It's a trivial fix from SQL Server side, but I guess this can be unnatural to a way EF works. If that's not possible what is my best alternative?

I'm using EF 6.1

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I want FK, but with no FK constraint. That's `Enforce Foreign Key Constraint` option in SQL Server relationship editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I begin to think that such weak relationship actually makes no sense -- it doesn't really enforce anything, there is really no benefits of having it. So I ended up removing this relationship completely since I can always get other part using PK of either `Product` or `Knowledge`.

Answer (score 1):

The Product needs to be configured as optional for the Knowledge.  Altering the code from [MSDN Entity Framework Fluent API - Relationships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToOptional) page to match your example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasRequired(p => p.Knowledge)
        .WithOptional();

    base.OnModelBuilding(modelBuilder);
}
```

Which gives a table structure where the required-to-optional relationship is enforced and the primary key on the Product is also the ForeignKey for the Knowledge relationship.

Tested quickly with the following results (success or failure being determined at DbContext.SaveChanges()):

1. Creating and adding a new Product (p) with a new Knowledge (k) - Succeeds
2. Creating and adding a new Knowledge (k') alone - Succeeds
3. Creating and adding a new Product (p') and assigning the Knowledge (k') - Succeeds
4. Creating and adding a new Product (p'') and assinging the Knowledge (k') - Succeeds -- *it should be noted that p'' overwrites p' in the context, but p' continues to exist until disposed.*
5. Creating and adding a new Product (p''') with no Knowledge - Fails

Comment: Thanks, but 0..1-0..1 assumes that both `Product` and `Knowledge` can be created without other side, i.e. your case 5 fails in that aspect. I begin to think that such weak relationship actually makes little sense (it doesn't really enforce anything), so I ended up removing relationship completely since I can always get other part using PK.